# A shell script to kill a process, whenever it is found to be running

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal, sh

I am trying to write a script (which is always running in the background) to kill a process whenever it is found to be running.

The script always exits after an iteration of the loop. How do i fix this problem?

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PROCESS=`ps A | grep iTunes | grep -v grep`

for i in 'seq 1 $max'
do
        if [ "$?" -ne "1" ]; then
                killall iTunes
        fi
done
```

Comment: Your script contains multiple syntax errors.  Moreover, what is `max`.  Consider reading a tutorial to learn about the syntax.

Comment: You set `PROCESS` but don't use it anywhere. The value of `$max` doesn't seem to be set anywhere. If you're using single quotes on your `'seq 1 $max'` as you show and not back-ticks, then your loop will run 1 time (with value `$i = 'seq 1 $max'`) and stop.

Comment: Well, I am very new to shell scripting. 15 mins to be precise!

Comment: How long do you want the script to run? Forever? And how are you running it? Cron job? If you've been at this 15 minutes, then it sounds like you have some studying to do before asking what's wrong with your code. ;) There are numerous tutorials online.

Comment: I'll be running this script in terminal (for as long as i want it to) and no, it's not a cron job.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#!/bin/bash
killProc() {
    while true
    do
        killall -9 $1 2>&1 >> /dev/null
        sleep $2
    done
}
killProc iTunes 5 #This will kill iTunes every 5 seconds.
```

Comment: Two loops aren't necessary

Answer (score 1):

Run a command like this:

```
while sleep 60;do killall iTunes;done
```

To run the command every five minutes, run `crontab -e` (or `EDITOR=nano crontab -e`) and add a line like this:

```
*/5 * * * * killall iTunes
```

Another option is to save this plist as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/killitunes.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>killitunes</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>killall</string>
    <string>iTunes</string>
  </array>
  <key>StartInterval</key>
  <integer>300</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then run `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/killitunes.plist`.